# ¿Es correcto escribir "quiero saber si sí se realizó"?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, acentuación, preguntas, condicional

El primer *si* lo escribo sin tilde considerando que es una condicional, el segundo con tilde porque se trata de una afirmación.
También me pregunto si es necesario el uso de alguna coma u otro signo de puntuación.

Comment: **Quiero saber sí, si se realizó**. Pero es lenguaje hablado. Hay que poner el sí primero. Sería lo más lógico.

Comment: @Lambie: Su comentario es erróneo. El orden de "sies" que propone Boris es el correcto. La coma que Vd. introduce no  es necesaria y no es correcta. Y esa construcción se utiliza no solo en el lenguaje hablado sino también en el escrito.

Comment: @Alcor, Se diria solo: **"Quiero saber si se realizó"**. Es una oración normativa. Pero **este** hablante lo dice poniendo dos sis juntos. *Yo, sí, quiero saber si x se realizó*.

Comment: No tengo suficiente espacio aqui pero digo esto. La pregunta de Boris solo viendria **en un diálogo de tipo**: ¿ Quieres saber (o no ) si el projecto se realizó? Respuesta: Quiero saberlo **sí**, si se realizó [or no]. Pero hay varias maneras de imaginar este diálogo. Si no hay diálogo, la persona vendria y diria: **Quiero saber si el proyecto se realizó**. Poner el condicional en primero lugar y la afirmación en segundo lugar me parece un poco estraño. Y eso en cualquier idioma....

Comment: En la pregunta de Boris, el adverbio afirmativo "sí" se refiere al verbo "se realizó". "sí" podría ir entre comas después de "Quiero saber" si se refiriera a "Quiero saber". El resultado serían dos oraciones totalmente distintas en cuanto a su significado.

Comment: A mí ese "si sí" me parece perfectamente normal y correcto, como bien explica Ananias en su respuesta.

Comment: El comentario anterior debería haberse dirigido a otro usuario. Gracias.

Comment: El problema no está con el si sí. está en que no hay **o no**.  Nadie diria "si sí" sin tambien decir "o no". Entonces, **está correcto pero no "completo"**. No sé porque no sea obvio para los nativos hablantes.

Answer (score 5):

La oración:

- Quiero saber si sí se realizó. (primer "si" sin tilde, segundo "sí" con tilde)

está correctamente escrita sin comas(*) pero resulta redundante. La conjunción "si" (sin tilde) alcanza para introducir preguntas indirectas (ese "si" no es condicional, sino el "si" que introduce proposiciones nominales en discurso indirecto: Quiero saber ESTO, o sea, si se realizó):

- Quiero saber si se realizó.

Si deseamos enfatizar el verbo con un adverbio afirmativo, sería más elegante y eufónico decir:

- Quiero saber si efectivamente se realizó.

(*) Solo se usarían comas si primero apareciera la afirmación, pero el resultado sería una oración quebrada, un tanto atípica inclusive en la lengua oral (*Quiero saber, sí, si se realizó*) cuando lo normal sería decir: Sí, quiero saber si se realizó. En este caso, "sí" se referiría a "quiero saber", no a "se realizó", como es la intención de la oración original.

Comment: @Alcor La propuesta de Gustavson no es más correcta gramaticalmente hablando, pero sí es más correcta, en general y en mi opinión, pues evita la repetición del mismo sonido al expresarla en voz alta y en cualquier caso evita la redundancia que menciona en su primer párrafo.

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta de acuerdo con lo sugerido. No obstante, insisto en que la alternativa con "efectivamente" es muy superior.

Comment: Con la alternativa que propone ("efectivamente") o un término similar la oración queda, en efecto, más elegante y eufónica que con la repetición "si sí" original. Totalmente de acuerdo con Vd. y con @RubioRic.

Answer (score 2):

Es **totalmente correcto** escribir (o decir): "quiero saber si sí se realizó", **en ese orden y sin comas interpuestas**.

Por poner un ejemplo, supongamos un cuestión planteada en una comisión:

- "Pregunta dirigida al Sr. XX: ***En relación con el proyecto de desinfectar las residencias, quiero saber si sí se realizó dicha desinfección y, si no se realizó, por qué motivos no se realizó.***"

Como se ve, no tiene por qué formar parte de un diálogo, como [a mi modo de ver erróneamente] recalca @Lambie en su respuesta. Es una simple pregunta, no un diálogo.

Como indica [a mi modo de ver acertadamente] @Gustavson en su respuesta, el segundo "si" no es necesario (salvo para dar mayor énfasis) y en caso de querer mantener el énfasis existen alternativas igualmente válidas y que incluso "suenan" mejor al evitar la duplicidad "si sí".

Con el mismo ejemplo, valgan algunos ejemplos:

- "*En relación con el proyecto de desinfectar las residencias, **quiero saber si se realizó** dicha desinfección o no y, si no se realizó, por qué motivos no se realizó.*"
- "*En relación con el proyecto de desinfectar las residencias, **quiero saber si se realizó o no** dicha desinfección y, si no se realizó, por qué motivos  no se realizó.*"

Pero si se quiere poner énfasis en la pregunta:

- "*En relación con el proyecto de desinfectar las residencias, quiero saber si* **efectivamente se realizó** *dicha desinfección y, si no se realizó, por qué motivos no se realizó.*"
- "*En relación con el proyecto de desinfectar las residencias, quiero saber si* **realmente se realizó** *dicha desinfección y, si no se realizó, por qué motivos  no se realizó.*"
- "*En relación con el proyecto de desinfectar las residencias, quiero saber si* **en efecto se realizó** *dicha desinfección y, si no se realizó, por qué motivos no se realizó.*"

y así *ad nauseam*.

Comment: Como dije:  **si sí se realizó dicha desinfección o no**", pero no sin el "o no". Es exactamente lo que dije. Lo puse en mi último ejemplo. Por lo menos es lenguaje hablada. Ningún tio se levanta en una asamblea y dice: Quiero saber si sí se realizó. Y tu proprio ejemplo (el primero tiene **o no** al final).

Comment: @Lambie: No entiendo lo que dice o intenta decir. ¿Podría ser más explicito/explicita/explicite para que su comentario fuera más inteligible?

Comment: Primero dices que el orden está bien (como lo puso Boris) y segundo que vas a dar un ejemplo ficticio. ¿Hasta ahí me sigues? Vale. Pues bien, el ejemplo ficticio contiene *o no*. Eso fue lo que comenté en *mi último ejemplo*. El **D)**.  O sea, nadie diría "si sí se realizó"como dice Boris sin un "o no" en alguna parte de la oración.  Ahora está claro? :) [soy mujer]

Comment: @Lambie: **Le ruego que se abstenga de tutearme y utilice el género y pronombre correcto, tal y como refleja mi perfil**. En cuanto a su segundo comentario, me temo que, para mi, no aclara suficientemente lo escrito en su primer comentario _ut supra_. ¿No está Vd- de acuerdo con el orden señalado por Boris? ¿Cree Vd. que hacen falta comas?

Comment: Muy bien. No hay problema: Usted.  Pusé soy mujer **para mi caso** porque Ud. dijo "explicito/explicita/explicite". Ahoro ya puede saber que en mi caso sería **explicita**. Repito por *tercera o quarta vez*: el problema no está en el "si sí se realizo". Está en la falta del "o no". Conclusión: No estoy de acuerdo con Boris porque no es una frase correctamente estructurada como para reflejar lo que realmente se diria. Por favor, pare de decir que no está claro. Lo he dicho en mi respuesta y tres veces aqui. No creo que haya manera de decirlo mas claramente.

Answer (score -3):

La pregunta: ¿Es correcto escribir "quiero saber si sí se realizó"? tiene que venir con un diálogo, que sea explicito o no. **Sin diálogo no tendria sentido.**

A)

- Mario: ¿Quieres saber si el proyecto se realizó?
- Juan: Quiero saberlo **sí**, **si se realizó [o no]**.

B)

- Mario: ¿Quieres saber si el proyecto se realizó?
- Juan: Sí, quiero saberlo, **si se realizó [o no]**.

C)

- Mario: ¿Quieres saber si el proyecto se realizó?
- Juan: Quiero saber **si sí o no** se realizó.

D)

- Mario: ¿Quieres saber si el proyecto se realizó?
- Juan: Quiero saber **si sí** se realizó.

La frase D) **presta a confusíon.** Creo que se diría "sí o no" **pero no "si sí" sin más nada.** Se puede decir pero suena un poco raro. **Es correcto pero no completo.**

Es obvio que cualquier frase con *sí y/o* no se refiere a una pregunta.

Comment: No es necesario añadir la pregunta para dar contexto, es una petición. 

Suponga que llega a una recepción y hace la consulta: "Quisiera saber si efectivamente se realizó", mi duda era si es posible utilizar "sí", para enfatizar interés en que se haya realizado.

Comment: @Boris: No sé si sí me crees. Te suena? O mejor: No sé si sí me crees o no.  Y claro: "Quisiera saber si efectivamente se realizó", pero esta no fue tu pregunta. Me han hecho caminar sobre ascuas para algo bastante sencillo.

Comment: No puedo estar de acuerdo, otros lo comprendieron, sin embargo usted colocó el primer sí con tilde, cambiando el sentido y provocando la confusión. Evidentemente no pregunté "Quisiera saber si efectivamente se realizó", ya que es correcto, mi duda supone utilizar síes consecutivos.

Comment: @Boris: Pusé **cuatro frases diferentes**. Parece que os gusta no comprender adrede lo que dije. Y me hacéis repetir el mismo canto varias veces.